# (JS) SPA-like website behavior with background videos

Tags: javascript, ajax, video, single-page-application

Forgive me if another thread like this exists - I couldn't find the answer to that specific problem.

I'll soon be developing the frontend for a vanilla JS AJAX loaded website, with SPA-like behavior similar to the home slider in this one:
- http://clapat.ro/themes/grenada-wordpress

The methodology I will probably utilize is loading the innerHTML of a container from the targeted sub-template, then pushing the state to the history - pretty standard approach to this, I believe.

Now, the slides containing image background are pretty obvious - all it should take is placing the same image in the target subpage hero section, then animating in on load. The problem might be with the video slides - how to make them continue playing seamlessly during and after the reload? Will such approach force them to start all over from the beginning, as soon as the target page is loaded and placed in the view?

I haven't tried it yet, I thought I'd ask in advance, in order not to get myself stuck up all the way into the incorrect approach :)

Thank You in advance,
Peter

Comment: Am I right in that you want to swap the rendered contents by replacing the "current" HTML elements with new ones via setting `innerHTML`? If yes, that will of course force any playing video to stop and start all over again, because you removed the `<video>` element that played the video.

Comment: Thanks, I see... Is there an alternative approach that rectifies this problem? I see they've managed to achieve it somehow in the template I linked - as well as several other websites I've seen online -  yet I have no idea how it could be done.

Maybe something like keeping the original video object from the homepage slide, and then appending it to the hero when the next page is loaded, would be a better way then?

Answer (score 0):

Researching the reference templates for the 100th time, I think I came up with some kind of a solution myself:

if both the homepage and target page had structure like:

```html
<body>
  <main-container>
    <slider-or-hero-container>
    ...
    </slider...>
    <content-container>
    ...
    </content...>
  </main-container>
</body>
```

Then, maybe I could replace the whole "main-container" on normal links, but replace only "content-container" clicking the links within the slider? The slider section would basically just stay, and the script would simply modify its appearance (disabling arrows and slide change, perform the transition animations etc)...

If you had any suggestions at this point, I'll really appreciate that :) Otherwise, I will post an update when I'm done coding it - if it works, it may be helpful for someone in the future :)